# The web address incorrect error

Tags: iis-8

I am new to windows 2012 server as well as iis8. I try to host a sample page with domain name in IIS8. I got following error

> Make sure the web address http://www.mytest.com:1024 is correct

How can I rectify this? First created a new website called `MyTest` and assigned the ip address and port number to that site and set the domain as `www.mytest.com`.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

My code in html page is

```
<html>
<body>
Welocme
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try executing your page using url like

```
http://localhost:1024
```

Comment: i just tried http://localhost:1024/ for that also i got the same error http 400 bad request